# How can I create a JTA-aware EntityManager in WebLogic 12c with a data-source not known at compile time?

Tags: jpa, weblogic, eclipselink, jta

I am working on an application, to be deployed in WebLogic 12c, which needs to be able to obtain a JPA EntityManager (EclipseLink 2.5.2) connected to an arbitrary Data Source at runtime. I do not currently know what the JNDI name of that Data Source will be; there will be several to many of them, connected to different databases but all with identical schemas. So the data source name cannot be specified in the persistence.xml inside the application; it must come from outside (configuration file most likely).

I don't think I can have an EntityManagerFactory or EntityManager injected; they are pretty tightly coupled to the configuration in persistence.xml and I do not seem to be able to override the JTA data source name. This, for example, does **not** work:

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="myPU")
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
// ...
    Map<String, Object> emProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    emProps.put(EntityManagerProperties.JTA_DATASOURCE, "jdbc/foobar");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(emProps);
```

My as my EntityManager here is still connected to the JTA datasource that was actually specified in the persistence.xml.

So I started looking at creating the EntityMangerFactory through non-injected means, like with `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(puName, propMap)` but here, it seems, no matter what persistence.xml *or* my property map says, I get a `RESOURCE_LOCAL` EntityManagerFactory!

How can I get an EntityManager or EntityManagerFactory that is JTA-enabled *and* associated with an arbitrary datasource name that is not known at compile-time?

Comment: The point of resources and JNDI lookup in a container that you can define the names required by an application, and then hook them up to actual resources later.  This allows you to define your persistence unit to look up a datasource of a particular name and then tie it to actual datasource.  You can't have a container managed persistence unit if it isn't configured to use container managed resources like the datasource and transaction controller.  They need to be known upfront by the container for it to properly manage everything.

Comment: I don't need it to be a container-managed persistence unit. I want a JTA-enabled EntityManager. Are you saying you can only have JTA if it's container-managed?

Comment: No, but how are you associating your transaction with your datasource?  This is all usually handled seamlessly by the container, by associating the datasource during deployment.  If you show how you are creating/getting the datasource at runtime, I'm sure someone can help you inject it into a persistence unit (EclipseLink has numerous properties and listeners that could be used), but at this point, what you are asking seems very open ended.

Comment: In the code you used above, the container is injecting the EMF which will have the datasource and properties already defined.  You would need to create your own EMF and pass in the datasource properties.

Comment: Yes, my problem - and I can try to make this clearer above - is that when I create my own EMF it is always RESOURCE_LOCAL even when I specify JTA in the properties. I know injection provides JTA connections, but we've already established injection isn't particularly dynamic. *Can* I create a JTA EMF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick, at least in EclipseLink 2.5.2:

```
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.TRANSACTION_TYPE, "JTA");
    properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JTA_DATASOURCE, "jdbc/foobar");
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPU", properties);
    JpaEntityManagerFactory jemf = (JpaEntityManagerFactory)emf;

    WebLogicTransactionController wlstx = new WebLogicTransactionController();
    if (jemf.getDatabaseSession() != null && jemf.getDatabaseSession().getExternalTransactionController() == null) {
        jemf.getDatabaseSession().setExternalTransactionController(wlstx);
    }
    if (jemf.getServerSession() != null && jemf.getServerSession().getExternalTransactionController() == null) {
        jemf.getServerSession().setExternalTransactionController(wlstx);
    }
```

By adding the transaction controller to the EMF, it is once again enlisted with JTA and will respect JTA transactions. My persistence.xml provides a dummy value for the JTA datasource; I override in code and away we go!

**NB**: Currently `getDatabaseSession()` and `getServerSession()` in fact return the exact same object. I could get away with only setting one of these, but this is undocumented and you're better off safely setting both of them, just to be sure.